# Align two div horizontally same line not working for bootstarp 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my HTML, I have two horizontally aligned divs. So, to align these divs in the same line, I'm utilising bootstrap classes. However, with this code, the second div appears underneath the first div.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto col-sm-12 col-md-12 mb-4 text-center">
        <div class="wow fadeInUp">
           <h2 class="section-head mb-5">Invite trainees  </h2>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <p class="mb-5 mx-auto b-500"> 
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.  
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">  
              <img src="images/vector.png" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
          
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question it is hard to read and also understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent div should have the class of **row**. Please try Below Code and check

`<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto col-sm-12 col-md-12 mb-4 text-center">
        <div class="wow fadeInUp row">
           <h2 class="section-head mb-5">Invite trainees  </h2>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <p class="mb-5 mx-auto b-500"> 
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
              bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.  
              </p>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">  
              <img src="images/vector.png" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

**div class with class .col should have parent div with class .row. so your code would be**

```
   <div class-'row>
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                  <p class="mb-5 mx-auto b-500"> 
                  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
                  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.  
                  </p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">  
                  <img src="images/vector.png" class="img-responsive">
               </div>
    </div>
```